# Cordova A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable

Tags: cordova

for a few days now I have been getting this error when everything worked fine before.
I have already done research on the web and any solution I have found none have worked

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                             

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 26s
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\comun\Desktop\Project APP\radio_matese_app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\comun\Desktop\Project APP\radio_matese_app\platforms\android\build.gradle
```

I hope someone will help me to resolve this situation because I am going crazy

Comment: no one who can tell me how to solve this problem I have been bumping into it for days I do not get out